# How to retrieve list of all components in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a list of "trusted" components inside my Android app, the logic would require me to deny access to a particular method if the caller isn't inside the aforementioned trusted data structure.

In an attempt to be a little more clear:
For a *trusted component* I mean a component (Activities and Services). 
The *trusted data structure* would be something pretty basic like a List of Strings, I just need to save somewhere the components names (com.example.MainActivity, for example). 
Therefore a *non-trusted component* would be any other component that wasn't inside the data structure.

The logic control flow would be to compare the caller of the method that I would need to "protect" and look for the caller name inside the data structure in order to allow/deny the access.

The only thing I could think of is to get a list of running services with ActivityManager's getRunningServices but it doesn't really leads nowhere...does anyone have some kink of knowledge around this? Thanks

Comment: What is a "trusted component"? What would be an example of a non-trusted component? What is a "trusted data structure"?

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right, sorry about that. Should be a little more clear now.

Comment: But, you are responsible for everything in your app. If you do not trust this component, why is it in your app in the first place? In Java/Kotlin, you do not readily have access to the caller, short of creating an `Exception` and examining the stack trace.

Comment: In my app there's an override method of EditText's getText(), I want that only "trusted component" can call it. I have to protect it from a reverse engineering process in which the attacker could load his own class and call that specific method which would need to be blocked...does that make sense?

Comment: If they are capable of reverse-engineering your app and modifying it, they are more than capable of modifying your list of strings that identify your trusted components.

Comment: It's a really specific scenario and attack surface, it's for a university project...if you want to keep thieves out of a home just don't have windows and doors, useless but secure.